# Need to get one row of result with subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

have sql query like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 1") AS test_1 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 2") AS test_2 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 3") AS test_3 
FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `content`
```

and getting result like this:

```
test_1, test_2, test_3
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
2,      7,      0
```

Need to get result just one row, like this:

```
test_1, test_2, test_3
2,      7,      0
```

How? What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Why did you group by content?

Comment: Is all these data coming from same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This.

```
SELECT  distinct 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 1") AS test_1 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 2") AS test_2 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 3") AS test_3 
FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `content`
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` often indicates a badly written query. Same here. Instead of writing a proper query, you kind of mend it's output. (And you don't answer "What's wrong with my query?"). -1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be rewrite like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN `content` = "test 1" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `content` = "test 2" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `content` = "test 3" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_3
FROM 
    `table_name`
WHERE 
    `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the TOP clause in your SELECT statement...

```
SELECT TOP 1
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 1") AS test_1 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 2") AS test_2 , 
(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `table_name` WHERE `custom_id` IN (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) AND `content` = "test 3") AS test_3 
FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `content`
```

Comment: The query is badly written. To keep it thus and muddle through with a top clause is a very bad solution. -1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing doesn't make much sense. You select from the table and group by content. That means you get one result row per content (one for 'test 1', one for 'test 2' etc.). There seem to be ten different content in your table, as you show that you get ten result rows.

Then for every such row, no matter what it contains, you are executing your three subqueries that always get the same results of course.

So either:

```
select 
  (select count(*) from table_name 
    where custom_id in (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) and content = 'test 1') as test_1 , 
  (select count(*) from table_name 
    where custom_id in (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) and content = 'test 2') as test_2 , 
  (select count(*) from table_name
    where custom_id in (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1) and content = 'test 3') as test_3 ;
```

or better:

```
select 
  sum(content = 'test 1') as test_1,
  sum(content = 'test 2') as test_2,
  sum(content = 'test 3') as test_3
from table_name
where custom_id in (10,9,8,6,5,4,3,2,1);
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: Why? What is wrong about this answer? I think I thoroughly explain what the original query does and why it is wrong and how to go about it. If you see a flaw in this, tell me. This is what this comment section is for.